# Select and group multiple range of dates in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to Select the same range of dates and group them by year. In this case I want the total of the bills of a customer per year from September and October.

My Code right now:

```
SELECT c.name, c.telefonnumber, TO_CHAR(b.billdate, 'YYYY'), sum(b.sume)
FROM customer c, bill b
WHERE b.customerId = c.id
AND b.datum BETWEEN '01.10.2016' AND '30.09.2016'
GROUP BY c.name, c.telefonnumber, TO_CHAR(b.billdate, 'YYYY');
```

This Query works perfectly but when I want to add another year the result is an endless loop:

```
AND b.datum BETWEEN '01.10.2016' AND '30.09.2016'
OR b.datum BETWEEN '01.10.2015' AND '30.09.2015'
```

I also tried to do it in a String way. In this case when I only look for the results of September it works perfectly, but again as soon as I add the **OR** it becomes again an endless loop:

```
AND TO_CHAR(kp.tmstmp) LIKE '%.09.%' 
OR TO_CHAR(kp.tmstmp) LIKE '%.10.%'
```

I know I am somehow missing something in the OR operator, but since this is only happening me with dates I am a bit confused.

Comment: When mixing AND and OR you should really use brackets around the things you are ORing. A common mistake to make and it's what is causing your query to hang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works fine and return 0 rows, I guess - exactly the number of dates between 01.10.2016 and 30.09.2016 :)

If you wish to check several ranges, you should enclose them into braces:

```
... and
  ( 
    b.datum between date '2016-10-01' and date '2017-09-30' or
    b.datum between date '2015-10-01' and date '2016-09-30' or
    ... 
  ) and
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your date criteria in the `WHERE` clause are being phrased incorrectly.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT c.name, c.telefonnumber, TO_CHAR(b.billdate, 'YYYY'), sum(b.sume)
FROM customer c, bill b
WHERE b.customerId = c.id AND
      (b.datum BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.10.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AND
                      TO_DATE('30.09.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') OR
       b.datum BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.10.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AND
                      TO_DATE('30.09.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

I made two changes, namely making certain that the date checks occur in one logical place, surrounded by outer parentheses, and that we use bona fide dates when comparing against the `datum` column.